# Find the range of values of $x+y+z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> If $x,y,z$ are positive reals satisfying $\frac{1}{3} \le xy+yz+ zx \le 3$, then find the range of values of $x+y+z$

This is from BMO 1993. I have applied AM GM and CS in every possible way my brain can think of. I do not think my working will be of any help to anyone, so I am not showing. Any kind of hint to full answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Please, anyone's any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the lower bound use the fact that $(x+y+z)^2 \geq 3(xy+xz+yz) \geq 3$ so $x+y+z \geq 1$. The equality is satifised for $  x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$

To prove there is no upper bound pick $x=n, y=\frac{1}{n}, z=\frac{1}{n} $ for some natural number $n$. Then the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Can you also tell the range for $xyz$?

Comment: The upper bound is $1/27$ and the lower bound is $0$.

Comment: So what did you apply?

Comment: The upper bound for xyz follows from AM-GM applied for xy+yz+zx. You then get xyz <=1. For the lower bound apply the same example as in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2 \geq 0. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now add $3(xy+yz+zx)$ and complete the square 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x+y+z)^2 \geq 3(xy+yz+zx) \geq 1. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So $1$ is a lower bound.